# What is the meaning of "@" in play routes?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, routes, url-routing

Sample routes file:

```scala
    GET     /test/api/chrome-extension-version     controllers.API.getChromeExtensionVersion()
    
    GET     /test/common/cache/config     @controllers.CommonController.updateConfigCache()
```

The application is written in Play 2.2.3. What is the significance of "@" and the difference between the above two function calls?

Comment: Also, Play 2.2 is quite deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the fact that the @ symbol telling it to look outside of the current path from where you're located.

Comment: I don't think so that it is outside the current path.